# Frequent GPU Panics

Tags: macbook-pro, kernel-panic

I'm just praying that I don't need to replace my logic board for this problem; I don't have applecare.

Randomly my computer shuts itself off, sometimes just the screen, sometimes the entire system restarts.  The error report seems to always relate to a GPU Panic.

Does anyone know how to read these error reports?  What do you think is causing this "Panic"

```
Anonymous UUID:       EB753096-DB11-4C07-807F-F583348D2E7C

Wed May  7 15:55:57 2014
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff7f8f4e4fb0): "GPU Panic: [<None>] 3 0 a0 d9 9 8 0 3 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0x102c00000 0xffffff81048d5000 0x0e7150a2, D0, P3/4\n"@/SourceCache/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.4.35/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:127
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8103e9b350 : 0xffffff800d222fa9 
0xffffff8103e9b3d0 : 0xffffff7f8f4e4fb0 
0xffffff8103e9b4a0 : 0xffffff7f8dbfa22c 
0xffffff8103e9b560 : 0xffffff7f8dcc4106 
0xffffff8103e9b5a0 : 0xffffff7f8dcc4176 
0xffffff8103e9b610 : 0xffffff7f8dee99de 
0xffffff8103e9b680 : 0xffffff7f8dce6c2d 
0xffffff8103e9b6a0 : 0xffffff7f8dc00c75 
0xffffff8103e9b750 : 0xffffff7f8dbfe780 
0xffffff8103e9b950 : 0xffffff7f8dbff820 
0xffffff8103e9ba30 : 0xffffff7f8dd9cc33 
0xffffff8103e9baa0 : 0xffffff7f8dd9cdf5 
0xffffff8103e9bac0 : 0xffffff7f8dd9cdc0 
0xffffff8103e9bae0 : 0xffffff7f8dd922c5 
0xffffff8103e9bc70 : 0xffffff7f8dbac614 
0xffffff8103e9bcf0 : 0xffffff7f8db9bee2 
0xffffff8103e9bd70 : 0xffffff7f8db9f0d1 
0xffffff8103e9bdb0 : 0xffffff7f8db9e9a4 
0xffffff8103e9be20 : 0xffffff7f8db6658a 
0xffffff8103e9be60 : 0xffffff7f8db6583e 
0xffffff8103e9be90 : 0xffffff7f8db61b4a 
0xffffff8103e9bef0 : 0xffffff800d6ae0d0 
0xffffff8103e9bf30 : 0xffffff800d6acb72 
0xffffff8103e9bf80 : 0xffffff800d6acc47 
0xffffff8103e9bfb0 : 0xffffff800d2d7047 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[4421462D-2B1F-3540-8EEA-9DFCB0565E39]@0xffffff7f8db57000->0xffffff7f8db8efff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[EDA75271-4E9D-34E7-A2C5-14F0C8817D37]@0xffffff7f8d8ba000
         com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[999E29DA-D513-3544-89D1-9885B728A098]@0xffffff7f8db9a000->0xffffff7f8dba9fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[4421462D-2B1F-3540-8EEA-9DFCB0565E39]@0xffffff7f8db57000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[EDA75271-4E9D-34E7-A2C5-14F0C8817D37]@0xffffff7f8d8ba000
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.4.35)[1BFF66C1-65E4-3BB3-9DEE-B61C3137019B]@0xffffff7f8f4d7000->0xffffff7f8f4e9fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.4.35)[09897896-ACBD-36B5-B1D4-0CCC4000E3B3]@0xffffff7f8f4cf000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[045D5D6F-AD1E-36DB-A249-A346E2B48E54]@0xffffff7f8e4cb000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[EDA75271-4E9D-34E7-A2C5-14F0C8817D37]@0xffffff7f8d8ba000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[4421462D-2B1F-3540-8EEA-9DFCB0565E39]@0xffffff7f8db57000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.0.4)[E04639C5-D734-3AB3-A682-FE66694C6653]@0xffffff7f8f4d2000
         com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(8.2.4)[3D591202-DD24-3441-925A-F6808ABDF185]@0xffffff7f8dbaa000->0xffffff7f8de0efff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[EDA75271-4E9D-34E7-A2C5-14F0C8817D37]@0xffffff7f8d8ba000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[999E29DA-D513-3544-89D1-9885B728A098]@0xffffff7f8db9a000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[4421462D-2B1F-3540-8EEA-9DFCB0565E39]@0xffffff7f8db57000
         com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal(8.2.4)[ACFCEA0C-4C80-36C0-8636-D10EE7D2DE17]@0xffffff7f8de19000->0xffffff7f8dfc5fff
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(8.2.4)[3D591202-DD24-3441-925A-F6808ABDF185]@0xffffff7f8dbaa000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[EDA75271-4E9D-34E7-A2C5-14F0C8817D37]@0xffffff7f8d8ba000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
13C1021

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 13.1.0: Wed Apr  2 23:52:02 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.92.1~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: E9CF78E2-1E9F-3B6F-81A4-FEE6C6D0E4D5
Kernel slide:     0x000000000d000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff800d200000
System model name: MacBookPro10,1 (Mac-C3EC7CD22292981F)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 5666742200
last loaded kext at 5205820132: com.bresink.driver.BRESINKx86Monitoring 9.0 (addr 0xffffff7f8f5e7000, size 16384)
loaded kexts:
com.bresink.driver.BRESINKx86Monitoring 9.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   80.14
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.2.3f10
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.0.9d1
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.15
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.13
com.apple.GeForce   8.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   2.6.0f1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.6.0f1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.4d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   4.2.3f10
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelMCEReporter  104
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 1.1.2
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.2.3f10
com.apple.nvidia.NVDAStartup    8.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.6.0f1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   8.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 8.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.4.35
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.3.5
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.1.12
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.5.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    666.4.0
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.8.1b2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   700.20.22
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   660.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   670.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 216.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   153
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   216.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.2.3f10
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  245.13
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.7
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.6.6
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily 98.14
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal    8.2.4
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman  8.2.4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.2.3f10
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.6.0f1
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.9.5fc2
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.14
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    2.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.2.3f10
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.7.0d10
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.6.0f1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.6.0f1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   91
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    98.14
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.4.35
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.4.35
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.11d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 240.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    3.1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    3.1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 1.4.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  660.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   650.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  656.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    2.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 3.2.7
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b4
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 660.4.2
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   630.35
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.6.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 675.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  278.11
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 371.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  23
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
Model: MacBookPro10,1, BootROM MBP101.00EE.B02, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.3 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.3f36
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In, 1024 MB
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533642465238432D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533642465238432D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xEF), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.2.3f10 13477, 3 services, 23 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM256E, 251 GB
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB Receiver
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 23.4
```

Comment: Try running this non invasive app to get a good profile of your system EtreCheck. http://www.etresoft.com/etrecheck it might give you more information.

Comment: Can you tell us, how it worked out for you?

Comment: I apologize for not leaving an update here. I learned that these panics can be caused by several things. My machine required a new logic board due to a bad video card.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem with the MacBook Pro Mid 2014 Model. Check out this link http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4088?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US. Basically check with your local Genius Bar and update your software. It is a hardware problem so there is no way to fix it through software other than running the graphics off the CPU only. Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm sorry I should have specified, I have a Mid-2012 model?  Does this still apply, it specifies Mid-2010 in article?

Comment: I don't know if it will still be the same problem with the Mid-2012 model. It might because they use the same line of GPU. You can always take it to your local genius bar and show it to them and they can tell you what they can do (and any associated costs).

Answer (score 1):

The last loaded kext before the panic was `com.bresink.driver.bresinkx86mlnitoring`.  Do you have any Bresnik software on your computer?  Try uninstalling it and see if that helps.

If it doesn't, I agree with Appleguy1999: the backtrace of the panic shows GPU kexts, so it *could* be a GPU issue if an OS X reinstall doesn't work (to reinstall all the systems kexts). So if removing the Bresnik stuff *and* reinstalling your OS doesn't help, definitely [visit the Genius Bar](http://concierge.apple.com/reservation/us/en/techsupport/).  Appointments are always free; repairs not necessarily so.

Comment: Bresnik software is my temperature monitor.  I installed it to see if I could prevent this from happening so its probably not that. However, you pointing that out gives me an idea of what I might need to look for to identify the problem..  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may be happy to hear that Apple has acknowledged this hardware related issue and there's a Macbook Pro Repair Extension program: http://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/

As part of the program you will receive a free repair should those issues appear (probably a logicboard/mainboard swap)

Affected are the following models:

- MacBook Pro (15-inch Early 2011)
- MacBook Pro (15-inch, Late 2011)
- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2012)
- MacBook Pro (17-inch Early
  2011)
- MacBook Pro (17-inch Late 2011)
- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15 inch,
  Early 2013)